# The syncronization tag is a misspelling. How can it be deleted?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [**`syncronization` tag**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syncronization) is a misspelling of the [**`synchronization` tag**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronization).

There were only 4 posts in the tag, so I edited the tag misspelling in all of those posts; however, the [**`syncronization` tag still exists**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syncronization).... How can it be deleted / marked for deletion?
[image]

Comment: Why do I get a feeling "The syncronization tag is a misspelling.." is grammatically incorrect? delicious irony..?

Comment: @DMin - It'd only be ironic if I had misspelled the title. The quagmire that is known as English grammar is above my pay grade.

Comment: Ah! who cares. Just playing brother ;)

Comment: @DMin - I detected the jocular nature of your comment. My response was an attempt at lighthearted humor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should go away next time we tune the tags, this background process runs once a day.